# Cannot install rdkit in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, rdkit

I have spent many hours trying to build RDKit on ubuntu 11.10 for
Python 2.7 (rdkit_201106+dfsg.orig.tar.gz) using a precompiled version
of boost 1.49.  And I am failing miserably.

The recurring error is in the CMake GUI:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (install):

  install FILES given no DESTINATION!



  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_pytest):


  Unknown CMake command "add_pytest".
```

Any help please?

Solved the previous problem but now i get this error when running python even though I installed rdkit following the installation procedure:

```
 from rdkit import Chem
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named rdkit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have the environment variables set:
(you might need to fix the paths with what you have): using bash on mac:

```
export RDBASE=/usr/local/share/RDKit
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

you might want to add those lines to a bash script to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS setting this environment variables works for me

```
export RDBASE=/usr/share/RDKit
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
```